# Did John Steinbeck say "It means very little to know that a million Chinese are starving unless you know one Chinese who is starving"?

Tags: quotes, literature

I often see the quote attributed to [John Steinbeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Steinbeck), "It means very little to know that a million Chinese are starving ...", when explaining the difference between sympathy and empathy, e.g. from [Virtual Enterprise](https://vemckee.weebly.com/design-thinking-empathy.html) or [Time.com](https://time.com/collection-post/4101705/refugee-crisis-empathy/).

> As John Steinbeck wrote: “It means very little to know that a million
> Chinese are starving unless you know one Chinese who is starving.”

But I can't find the exact source of this quote. I am not an expert on John Steinbeck, but from I what know his works talked very little about China/Chinese people so I have a bit of doubt that he actually said that and wonder under what circumstance did he say that (if he did)?

Comment: Sounds like a variety of the old saying "A single death is a tragedy, a million deaths is a statistic", which is commonly attributed to Joseph Stalin.

Comment: @Philipp: there is also a Polish poet (I forgot their name) who said "a million and one is still a million", this was about the casualties in a war IIRC

Comment: "...from I what know his works talked very little about China/Chinese people..." - East of Eden features a main character who is Chinese, and through his eyes, Steinbeck sympathetically portrays the plight of Chinese individuals who came to the US (sometimes unwillingly) in the early 20th century. It does not feature this exact quote, but seems relevant to research on Steinbeck's view of the matter.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, Steinbeck wrote the 1941 film [The Forgotten Village](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forgotten_Village) and then published a book version with 136 photos from the film.

The preface of the [book version](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Forgotten_Village/M70eAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=starving) has the quote:

> A great many documentary films have used the generalized method, that is, the showing of a condition or an event as it affects a group of people. The audience can then have a personalized reaction from imagining one member of that group. I have felt that this is the more difficult observation from the audience's viewpoint. It means very little to know that a million Chinese are starving unless you know one Chinese who is starving. In *The Forgotten Village* we reversed the usual process. Our story centered on one family in one small village...

Comment: Why would he write such a "obscure" words then? He was no Chinese expert.

Comment: @Qiulang The 1928-1930 famine in China was a very well known event in the United States. Americans donated through the China International Famine Relief Commission, tried to help.

Comment: As a Chinese I feel ashamed that I don't know **China International Famine Relief Commission**, although after google it I realize that I knew its Chinese name.

Comment: When talking about Chinese Famine the instinct reaction is Mao's Famine, then I realized we had several greate famines in 20th century.

Comment: @Qiulang This is a history of the Commission: https://archive.org/details/historyofchinain00nath/mode/2up I don't know much about it personally.

Comment: For those who may be interested in this charity, its Chinese name is [华洋义赈会](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8D%8E%E6%B4%8B%E4%B9%89%E8%B5%88%E4%BC%9A/3330392). It was shutdown after Japanese invasion.

Comment: @DavePhD: well, that famine is barely known to our contemporaries though. Only has a couple of paras in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_famine_of_1928%E2%80%931930 And it was succeeded by another during the Sino-Japanese war. Given the year when the film came out, it's possible it was more a ref to the latter. That war was also cause célèbre in the US.

Comment: "Why would he write such a "obscure" words then?" What does that mean? What words are obscure?

Comment: @Acccumulation what I meant was that I assumed his reader didn't know much about China so those words may sound unfamiliar to them.

Comment: @Fizz 1920-21 also had the attention of Americans https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/10021978/1921-04-27/ed-1/seq-13/

Comment: @Qiulang says "*his reader didn't know much about China*". They might not have known much about China itself, but they did know about the famine. "Finish your dinner; people are starving in China!*" was a common saying from mothers to their finicky eating children. ¶ The expression was also used for Europe, as in the humorous 1960s song in which Alan Sherman explains how he became fat: [Hail To Thee, Fat Person — Lyrics](https://genius.com/Allan-sherman-hail-to-thee-fat-person-lyrics) and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5eSba-dLh8&ab_channel=AllanSherman-Topic).

Comment: @RayButterworth This 1931 Harpers article does the opposite, wants people to stop eating.  ""Go  in  and  tell  them  it's  all  over," 
she  suggested  to  Hilda  the  waitress. 
"Tell  them  people  are  starving  in 
China."" https://archive.org/stream/harpersmagazine164decalde/harpersmagazine164decalde_djvu.txt  I wonder when parents started saying it to get kids to eat? My parents would say it, but they would say India instead of China.

Comment: Although I appreciate all the information about the famine, can we just stop on that?

Comment: @Qiulang The words are in an introduction to a book about the famine. So the reader knew enough to buy the book (unless it was a gift), and they're about to learn more. And the statement could just as easily be about any widespread problem. In modern media, it's about "putting a face" on the disaster.

Comment: When I was growing up in the 60's I think the proverbial starving kids were in Africa. That's when we started seeing PSAs on TV for sending relief money to the Third World.

Comment: @Qiulang - I don't think its much appreciated these days how the US in the 20th century had a special regard for China, as a nation that should be a fellow continental power, but was instead suffering under the effects of colonialism (and then Communism).

Comment: @T.E.D. yes, sadly that is the current situation.